# deciding whether a map is a submap of the other in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have two maps, say
H[1]=1, H[2]=2
and
J[1]=1, J[2]=2, J[3]=3

I could then say map H is a submap of J. Is there a simple and efficient way in c++ to decide this?
Thank you:)

Comment: Perhaps [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) or [`std::includes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) will prove useful.

Comment: @chris definitely includes.